# C# Sort Array by multiple different conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I got an array which contains items of the object 'Person'

[image: IS]

I need to have the special people on top (those sorted by Id) and the nonspecial people below (those sorted alphabetically). It should look like this:

[image: SHOULD]

Is there a way of sorting it like this without having to split the list, sort it individually and then merging it back together?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you can `OrderBy` by `Special` (note that `false < true`) and then you can use *condition* within `ThenBy` like this:

```
var result = persons
  .OrderBy(person => person.Special != "Yes")
  .ThenBy(person => person.Special == "Yes" ? person.Id : 0)
  .ThenBy(person => person.Special == "Yes" ? "" : person.Name);
```

Comment: I like the conditional sorting since i imagine that `true` is "higher" than `false`. But for all others i would make it more explicit: `persons.OrderBy(p => p.Special == "Yes" ? 0 : 1)...`

Answer (score 0):

A non-linq version:

```
list.Sort((a, b) =>
{
    if (a.Special != b.Special)
    {
        return a.Special ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name);
});
```